# При количестве символов больше заданного скрыть кнопку

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый день. Есть текстовое поле и кнопка. Если количество введенных символов больше 20, то кнопка должна пропасть.

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type='button' id="button">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function func(){
 var text_value = document.getElementById('text').value;

 if (text_value.length > 2){
  document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none";
 }else{
  document.getElementById('button').style.display = "inline-block";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" onkeydown="func()">
<input value="кнопка" type="button" id="button" >
```

Вариант 2 с [Jquery 2.1.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js):

```js
var length;
 
$("#text").on(' keydown', function(){  
  textln = $('#text').val().length; 
 
  if(textln < 23 ){
   $("#button").css({"display":"inline-block"});
  }  
});

$("#text").on('keypress', function(){  
  textln = $('#text').val().length; 
  
  if(textln > 19 ){
   $("#button").css({"display":"none"}); 
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text" >
<input value="кнопка" type="button" id="button" >
```

Answer (score 3):

На vue.js это делается так

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="message">
  <h1>{{ message.length }} / 20</h1>
  <button v-show="message.length <= 20">OK</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для отслеживания количества введенных символов в текстовом поле можно воспользоваться событием **input**.
А управлять видимостью кнопки удобно с помощью CSS.

```js
const limit = 20;
const input = document.getElementById('text');
const btn = document.getElementById('button');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (this.value.length > limit) {
   btn.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
   btn.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit">
```